# any help i want to insert my trigger class in the codes below any help?

Tags: apex

```
global with sharing class ScheduledOrgInfoFetch implements Schedulable {

    public static String sched = '0 2 1 * * ? *';  

    global static String ScheduledOrgInfoFetch() {
        ScheduledOrgInfoFetch SC = new ScheduledOrgInfoFetch();

            return System.schedule('My batch Job', sched, SC);
        }

    global static void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

        //GetAccessTokenNBaseURL.getSFOAuth();
        SaveRecords();
    }     

    global static void SaveRecords(){
        GetPackages.OrgPackages();
        GetAccessTokenNBaseURL.getSFOAuth();

    }  
}
```

my trigger class:

```
trigger StartInfoFetchSchedWhenSave on Client_Org_Info__c (after insert) { // When the client insert his Org credentials, this trigger will fire.

    if(Trigger.isAfter){
        // the trigger must run after insert to ensure that getOrgInfo method has a result that can be used by the Send_API method for GetSysOv

        ScheduledOrgInfoFetch.ScheduledOrgInfoFetch(); // calls the Schedulable class

    }

}
```

Comment: You generally call a batch class from a schedulable class. What do you want to specifically acheive ?

Comment: the codes is fine but i built an custom settings which my trigger cannot be use so my idea i want to inside my trigger class to that class how can i do that

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding your question. I think you’re asking how to call the call a trigger on Custom Setting object. Is that correct?

Comment: i want to insert my trigger class to my apex class which the code above how would i do that.

Comment: Sorry one more refinement. So you want to call you logic in trigger from another class, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you want to call some logic in your trigger from some other class.

I suggest you using some trigger pattern for your goal. Take a look at this article, specifically the Frameworks section.
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices

So basically you create a class which handles all the logic. And you can call any methods from that class anywhere in the code.